# How to handle errors when download Quickblox sdk for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, quickblox

I am new to quickblox, and I want to implement chat using quickblox in my application.

When I download quickblox ios sample chat demo, I am getting bunch of errors.

Here is screenshot of errors:

[image: ScreenShot]

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you are trying to compile project with Generics implemented in it in XCode 6. Unfortunately that feature supported only in XCode 7+.
So just update your XCode or ask quickblox team to fix this for XCode 6.